# Correcting spelling rule in StyleCop

Tags: stylecop

StyleCop rule SA1642 insists that my documentation header for constructors must begin with 'Initializes a new instance of...'.

Whereas I agree with the rule itself, I just can't bring myself to accept StyleCop enforcing spellings I consider ugly. It's 'initialises' with an 's'!!!

Is it possible to modify the expected text, or must I simply disable a sensible rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current StyleCop version doesn't support customization for documentation rules. And there are no short-term plans to support it.

As a possible workaround (instead of disabling the entire rule) you could refer to some third-party custom rules. For example, [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com) currently allows writing *"Initializes a new instance."* as well as *"Initializes a new instance of the Class1 class."*

So I guess it could be extended to also allow *"Initialises ..."*. But if you want to force "Initialises" and prohibit "Initializes" it seems you need to wait for customizable documentation rules support.

Answer (score 11):

In the latest stylecop settings you can set the "Culture for analysis" to en-GB in the options tab and it will use British spelling instead of American.

Comment: This works for me, it's now complaining that it should be spelt "Initialises"